# Why does PHP cache filesize() calls?

Tags: php, caching

I just spent hours going crazy over a strange bug in my code. I was making a PHP application using the Twitter Streaming API, writing new tweets to the end of a file. Sometimes, the file containing the tweets was being overwritten for seemingly no reason at all.

Eventually I found this buried in the [`filesize()` page in the php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php):

> Note: The results of this function are cached. See `clearstatcache()`
>   for more details.

It turns out PHP was caching the result of my `filesize()` calls on the file I'm storing the tweets in. Then when I called `filesize()` again, it actually returned a completely **wrong** value. (the old length of the file, from the previous call of the function).

Then in the [docs page for `clearstatcache()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php), I found this:

> When you use stat(), lstat(), or any of the other functions listed in
>   the affected functions list (below), PHP caches the information those
>   functions return in order to provide faster performance

And a little further down:

> Affected functions include `stat()`, `lstat()`, `file_exists()`,
>   `is_writable()`, `is_readable()`, `is_executable()`, `is_file()`, `is_dir()`,
>   `is_link()`, `filectime()`, `fileatime()`, `filemtime()`, `fileinode()`,
>   `filegroup()`, `fileowner()`, `filesize()`, `filetype()`, and `fileperms()`.

**Why does PHP cache results like these?** Why is the cache not invalidated when the file is changed? Faster performance is great, but surely not at the expense of valid results.

Comment: *Why does PHP cache results like these? Faster performance is great* Well you answered your question already

Comment: Why doesn't the cache invalidate itself when the file has been modified then?

Comment: Just imagine a 2GB file. And if php has to calculate the size every time new, only because you change a letter or two that would be a HUGE performance lost there! And I still don't really see what you would expect as an answer here

Comment: _“… and that, kids, is why we always want to read the manual first.”_

Comment: @Rizier123 I'm not certain if that is correct. The filesystem should maintain some sort of record of the file size. In linux I believe it is in the inode. Checking the size of a 2GB file shouldn't be any more expensive than checking the size of a 2KB file. Note that any interaction with the file system is still much more expensive than just interacting with memory.

Comment: `Why is the cache not invalidated when the file is changed?` Why not ask the actual developers of core PHP rather than the equivalent of asking random people on the street?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already mentioned, the result is cached to improve performance. Interacting with the file system is more expensive than most other operations.

The reason the cache isn't invalidated when there is a change in the filesystem is because that monitoring would be even more expensive. This would negate the value of caching the result.

As to why this is done at the expense of yielding unexpected results in some cases: It's just a trade-off. If it were not done this way I think asking why the result isn't cached would be an equally valid concern. Either way, it would either be up to you to cache the result, or flush the built in cache.